# SQL Server Reporting Services folder security management

Tags: reporting-services

Are there any command-line tool allowing user to configure roles in Reporting Services? I've tried to find it myself but without any success.

I'm trying to create script to help me managing folder security on my Reporting Services adding/removing/modifying user/groups roles to folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah well Reporting Services seems to have SOAP API which allows you to modify policy to folder. It's a bit messy, and requires rewriting whole policy for all requests but it still works. Creating a simple wrapper to make those calls easier shouldn't be a big problem :)

Some info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154052.aspx